# creating OSGi enabled jar for ORACLE (for Spring Roo - ORACLE db integration)

Tags: spring, oracle, osgi

I'm hitting the Spring Roo / Oracle OSGi driver issue that plenty of others have hit and seem to have solved.

"Springsource currently can't host an OSGi wrapped Oracle driver" so it appears you need to take you existing non-OSGi one a wrap it.

I've been following the steps [here](http://nidget.wordpress.com/2011/07/21/how-to-osgify-an-oracle-jdbc-driver-with-spring-roo/) with the driver for Oracle 11g, version 2's driver.

Got completely stuck with step 11,

11. Remove the faulty OSGI driver from the Felix repository:

    - Use “osgi ps” to retrieve the ID of the OSGI bundle to remove.
    - Use “osgi headers” to get the Bundle-SymbolicName of the corresponding OSGI bundle. Probably `com.oracle.roo.jdbc.ojdbc5` or `com.oracle.roo.jdbc.ojdbc6`.
    - Use `osgi uninstall –bundleSymbolicName com.oracle.roo.jdbc.ojdbcx`

I've no background with osgi at all and despite getting the `com.sun.security.auth.module` missing dependency indicated when you run:

```
roo> database reverse engineer --shema xxx
```

can't progress with the osgi phases to uninstall these dependencies from OSGi.

Could anyone console dump the commands to do this, however noddy.

Much appreciated - Roo allows a basic app to be build real fast, but roo-oracle is a drop of a cliff, compared to the ease and speed of everything else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The commands mentioned in my post (http://nidget.wordpress.com/2011/07/21/how-to-osgify-an-oracle-jdbc-driver-with-spring-roo/) are roo commands.

```
roo> osgi ps
START LEVEL 99
ID State Level Name
[ 0] [Active ] [ 0] System Bundle (3.0.7)
[ 1] [Active ] [ 1] jansi (1.5)
…
[ 68] [Resolved ] [ 1] com-oracle-roo-jdbc (11.2.0.2_0001)
```

This shows the id of the com-oracle-roo-jdbc bundle: 68

```
roo> osgi headers

…
com-oracle-roo-jdbc (68)
————————
Bnd-LastModified = 1309962402810
Build-Jdk = 1.6.0_07
Built-By = jplandrain
Bundle-Description = This bundle wraps the standard Maven artifact: ojdbc5-11.2.0.2.
Bundle-License = http://www.oracle.com
Bundle-ManifestVersion = 2
Bundle-Name = com-oracle-roo-jdbc
Bundle-SymbolicName = com.oracle.roo.jdbc.ojdbc5
Bundle-Vendor = Oracle (wrapped into an OSGi bundle by the Spring Roo project build system)
Bundle-Version = 11.2.0.2_0001
Created-By = Apache Maven Bundle Plugin
Export-Package = …
```

Check the details for the bundle com-oracle-roo-jdbc (68) and, in particular, the “Bundle-SymbolicName” value

```
roo> osgi uninstall com.oracle.roo.jdbc.ojdbc5
```

That’s it. Removed.

Comment: Thanks for your post - the original was useful in putting me on the right track - but for someone whos never dealt with osgi it got hairy when I started having to open generated JARs and meddle with the MANIFEST.MF in the containd WEB-INF dir. Might be worth modifying the original post to say something like, open the manifest, remove the following "..." from the imports section, then run roo>osgi install --url file:///c:\path\to\current\dir\oracle\file_generated_by_wrapper.jar Ok, this is hand-holding - but Roo is meant to make it easy...

Comment: Accepted. Thanks for clarifying - and esp your original post http://nidget.wordpress.com/2011/07/21/how-to-osgify-an-oracle-jdbc-driver-with-spring-roo/

Answer (score 3):

```
NOTE: "CMD>" indicates from the command prompt, "roo>" indicates from within the roo shell, which can be accessed from the command prompt, by typeing "roo", provided the roo binary in on the environment path.
```

To fix this I did:
    In directory with oracle jar file:

```
[1] CMD> mvn install:install-file -Dfile=ojdbc5-11.2.0.2.jar -DgroupId=com.oracle -DartifactId=ojdbc5 -Dversion=11.2.0.2 -Dpackaging=jar

[2] start roo, and run:
roo> addon create wrapper --topLevelPackage com.oracle.roo.JDBC --groupId com.oracle --artifactId ojdbc5 --version 11.2.0.2 --vendorName Oracle --licenseUrl http://www.oracle.com

[3] need to remove some dependencies from the generated file (com.oracle.roo.jdbc.ojdbc5-11.2.0.2.0001.jar in this case), open jar in 7zip or other and edit manifest.MF file and remove from the "Import-Package:" bit in MINIFEST.MF:
com.sun.security.auth.module
oracle.i18n.text,
oracle.i18n.text.converter
oracle.ons,oracle.security.pki

[4] install the following dependencies (get from http://ebr.springsource.com/repository/app/, search on this site for the groupIds below) into mvn:

CMD> mvn install:install-file -Dfile=com.springsource.javax.resource-1.5.0.jar -DgroupId=javax.resource -DartifactId=com.springsource.javax.resource -Dversion=1.5.0 -Dpackaging=jar

CMD> mvn install:install-file -Dfile=com.springsource.javax.transaction-1.1.0.jar -DgroupId=javax.transaction -DartifactId=com.springsource.javax.transaction -Dversion=1.1.0 -Dpackaging=jar

CMD> mvn install:install-file -Dfile=ojdbc5.jar -DgroupId=com.oracle -DartifactId=ojdbc5 -Dversion=11.2.0.2 -Dpackaging=jar

[5] in roo, run

roo> osgi install --url file:///c:\users\alex\com.springsource.javax.transaction-1.1.0.jar
roo> osgi install --url file:///c:\users\alex\com.springsource.javax.resource-1.5.0.jar
roo> osgi install --url file:///c:\path\to\current\dir\oracle\file_generated_by_wrapper.jar


[6] to check these files have made it ok type 

roo> osgi ps

gives:

[  62] [Active     ] [    1] Spring Roo - Wrapping - jline (0.9.94.0010)
[  63] [Active     ] [    1] Spring Roo - Wrapping - json-simple (1.1.0.0010)
[  64] [Active     ] [    1] Spring Roo - Wrapping - protobuf-java-lite (2.3.0.0001)
[  65] [Active     ] [    1] Spring User Agent Analysis - Client (1.0.2.RELEASE)
[  69] [Active     ] [    1] Java Resource API (1.5.0)
[  70] [Active     ] [    1] com-oracle-roo-jdbc (11.2.0.2_0001)
[  72] [Installed  ] [    1] Java Transaction API (1.1.0)

basically 'Active' is what you want - 

run:

roo> osgi start --url file:///c:\users\alex\com.springsource.javax.transaction-1.1.0.jar

to change 'Installed' to 'Active'

[7] in roo, run:
roo> database reverse engineer --schema <schema>

if you get a 'Framework error' then you need to open up the manifest of your jar and delete more oracle imports (the above list *should* be sufficient) - only remove from the imports section tho.

once you've changed the jar, reload into OSGi with:

roo> osgi uninstall --bundleSymbolicName com.oracle.roo.jdbc.ojdbc5
roo> osgi start --url  file:///c:\users\alex\com.oracle.roo.jdbc.ojdbc5-11.2.0.2.0001.jar

re-run:

roo> database reverse engineer --schema <schema> 

to verify. Add a table into the schema and get DBA to grant access to get stuff to actually be generated.
```

Comment: I note my current problem is that Roo keeps pulling the 10g rather than 11g library imports - currently struggling to find how roo does this. Also getting 'java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to obtain physical type metadata for type ' when doing 'roo>field string --fieldName transactionId --notNull' so roo-oracle integration not home and dry

Comment: Got Roo working with oracle - requires the imports resource and transaction (matching the mvn imports above) and one for the oracle ojdbc5 jar and one for the newly generated osgi jar, ensure the DBA has granted object create permissions (on the users table?) and Roo should start working. (I'll modify the post to include the required pom.xml imports - Monday)

Comment: I also had to remove the import of `oracle.xdb`. but after that it worked.

Comment: I had to remove many more, I lost track, several more oracle and sun jars. Also it appears the javax.transaction dependency is now provided as of roo 1.2.5, including the additional dependency led to an error of multiple dependency chains.

Answer (score 0):

So as of 2016 (Spring Roo 1.3.2) for who ever searching how to uninstall OSGi, below is what worked for me.

> roo> osgi uninstall **--bundleSymbolicName** "com.oracle.roo.jdbc.ojdbc6"
>
> Bundle 'com.oracle.roo.jdbc.ojdbc6' : Uninstalled!